# Cleaner way of dealing with dates in java / Quartz

Tags: date, datetime, syntax, quartz-scheduler, java-time

In order to programmatically schedule a job one day ahead (using quartz) I had to come up with this mess of code:

```
Date.from(LocalDateTime.from(Instant.now()).plusDays(1).toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-3)))
```

Isn't there a way of making this monstruous piece of code more clean, readable?

My goal is to simple pick this moment and add one day to it, no concerns about timezones or little differences in the duration of some given days.

### EDIT

To be more specific, I need a java.util.Date that represents one day more than when it is created.

Comment: Define a static method that wraps this code?

Comment: always a choice, but I'm having trouble to accept that native java doesn't have a simpler way of dealing with such things

Comment: I think the problem is that quartz still uses `java.util.Date` rather than `java.time` alternatives.

Comment: @LucasNoetzold: the primary issue is that date and time *are not simple*. Java *tried* to provide a simple API twice (`java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`) and both of them had some glaring faults that made the `java.time` package necessary. It's a bit verbose, but it's the first built-in API that gets most things right. It also gets a bit simpler if you don't mix them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title you picked asks for dates in Java in a general sense, but your question and your tags show that you might be interested in some Quartz-specific solutions, like these (assuming you're using `TriggerBuilder`):

```
TriggerBuilder tb = ...; // initialize your tb

// Option 1
Trigger trigger = tb
        .withSchedule(/* pick your flavor */)
        .startAt(DateBuilder.futureDate(1, DateBuilder.IntervalUnit.DAY))
        .build();

// Option 2
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
Trigger trigger2 = tb
        .withSchedule(/* pick your flavor */)
        .startAt(DateBuilder.tomorrowAt(now.getHour(), now.getMinute(), now.getSecond()))
        .build();
```

For more info check the [DateBuilder API](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/DateBuilder.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms with no preference I know of for one or the other. Either this one:

```
    Date sameTimeTomorrow = Date.from(Instant.now().plus(Duration.ofDays(1)));
```

Or this:

```
    Date sameTimeTomorrow = Date.from(Instant.now().plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```

Beware, however, that this adds 24 hours without any consideration of summer time or other anomalies. For example: In my time zone summer time ends in the night between October 27 and 28. So if I run the above on October 27 at 12 noon I will hit October 28 at 13 in my time zone because the time has changed. If I need to hit 12 noon again, I need:

```
    Date sameTimeTomorrow = Date.from(
            ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo")).plusDays(1).toInstant());
```

Please substitute your correct time zone.